# Facebook API Publish feeds in Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting some feeds on my pages thru facebook API which are published normally.
but those posts are appears on my fans feeds, (may be irritate them if these are too much in numbers, you can understand)

I want to post these feeds in group like

[image: Posting of feeds in Groups]

I am using **koala gem** which is posting feeds using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[user_id]/feed?message=""
```

Rails code

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(page[:token])
result = graph.put_object("me","feed",facebook_attributes(feedback))
```

Comment: You want to group posts with the same link?

Comment: I want to share what different people says about a product, this may be a summary of various comments which have user's picture and and their comments

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because posts are grouped by Facebook algorithms.